# Erase element by value from vector of pairs

Tags: c++, vector, c++20

Since **C++20**, we can erase an element by value from a vector by doing, for example:

```
std::vector<int> v = {10,20,30,40,50};
std::erase(v,30);
```

That's really convenient and all not to mention there's also `std::erase_if`.

However, what if we have a vector of pairs and we want to erase, only if the `second` value of the pair matches?

```
std::pair<int, std::string> foo = std::make_pair(1,"1");
std::pair<int, std::string> foo2 = std::make_pair(2,"2");

std::vector< std::pair<int, std::string> > v;
v.push_back(foo);
v.push_back(foo2);

std::erase(v, make_pair(1,"2"));    //This is not going to work!
```

So, is there a way to erase the element by the `second` value from a vector of pairs?

Comment: `erase_if` passing a lambda as a predicate?

Comment: @BiagioFesta I've tried writing the predicate, but got stumped by not knowing what argument(s) to pass to the predicate / what return value it should be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be something like:

```
std::erase_if(v, [](const auto& p){ return p.second == "2"; });
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ad214ba451e973d)